# How can I use use pandas' .map() method to create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in an existing Dataframe using pandas' `.map()` method to create a new column.

I want to add new column to this using `pandas.map()` method

```
data = {
    'age':[30,33,35,30,59],
    'Job':['unemployed','services','management','management','blue-collar'],
    'marital':["married","married","single","married","married"],
    'Default':['no','no','no','no','no'],
    'Balance':[1787,4989,1350,1476,0],
    'Housing':['no','yes','no','yes','no'],
    'Loan':['no','yes','no','yes','no'], 'Day':[19,11,16,3,5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Check out: [pandas.map()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-map/)

Comment: However? The solution you're looking for is to…

Comment: :) what was the problem? what was the error if you have faced to any error? explain your problem with samples and write your errors ...

Comment: i want to add new coloumn to this using pandas.map() method                              
       data = {'age':[30,33,35,30,59],
       'Job':['unemployed','services','management','management','blue-collar'],
       'marital':["married","married","single","married","married"],                          
 'Default':['no','no','no','no','no'],
       'Balance':[1787,4989,1350,1476,0],
       'Housing':['no','yes','no','yes','no'],
       'Loan':['no','yes','no','yes','no'],
              'Day':[19,11,16,3,5]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: @AdemuyiwaAhmed -- this additional information should be added to the posted question, not the comment, to make it easier for potential responders.  But, this additional information does not reveal the relationship between values in the new column and the existing columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I expect this question will be closed. But I suggest looking at some tutorials, as well as the docs that DarrylG already pointed you to. [This looks good](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-pandas-apply-applymap-and-map-5d3e044e93ff).

Comment: @DarrylG thanks for the support. from the DF the key default is what needed to be changed to default code. i know i can just edit the key to bear default code straight. but the task given on it is to use pandas.map() method to solve it and that is why am asking how to go about it

Comment: @AdemuyiwaAhmed -- it's still not clear what you are trying to do.  You mention "I know I can just edit the key to bear default code straight" (but not quite clear what this means).  To make it clearer, you should give an example of this,  and ask how you would do the same with a map.